# Optimizing performance of SciPy Minimize while using Concurrent.Futures?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, timeit

I'm trying to figure out how to speed up a `scipy.minimize` function.

`minimize()` is called thousands of times. I run it in parallel using a ProcessPoolExecutor. `bootstrap()` is the parent function.

```
def optimize_weights(forecasts, prices, instrument):
    guess = [1/forecasts.shape[1]] * forecasts.shape[1]
    bounds = [(0.0,1.0)] * forecasts.shape[1]
    cons = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda x:  1 - sum(x)}

    def function(w, forecasts, prices, instrument):
        wf = (w*forecasts).mean(axis=1)
        wf = wf*10/wf.std()
        wf = wf.clip(-20,20)
        l = accountCurve(wf, prices, slippage=instrument.slippage, per_contract_cost=instrument.per_contract_cost)
        return -l.sharpe()

    result = minimize(function, guess, (forecasts, prices, instrument), bounds=bounds, method='SLSQP', tol=0.0001, constraints=cons, options={'disp': False ,'eps' : 1e0})
    return result.x

def mp_optimize_weights(samples, prices, instrument):
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        return executor.map(partial(optimize_weights, prices=prices, instrument=instrument), samples)

def bootstrap(instrument, parallel_process=True):
    print("Parallel Process: ", parallel_process)
    forecasts = instrument.forecasts().dropna()
    prices = instrument.prices().reset_index('Contract', drop=True)
    prices = prices[forecasts.index]
    years = list(set(prices.index.year))
    years.sort()
    result={}
    for year in years:
        sample_length = np.int(prices[:str(year)].size/10)
        end_of_sample_selection_space = prices[:str(year)].tail(1).index[0] - pd.Timedelta(days=sample_length)
        sample_dates = pd.to_datetime(np.random.choice(prices[:end_of_sample_selection_space].index,100))
        if(sample_length > 50):
            samples = [forecasts.loc[date:date+pd.Timedelta(days=sample_length)] for date in sample_dates]
            if parallel_process is True:
                weights = pd.DataFrame(list(mp_optimize_weights(samples, prices[:str(year)], instrument=instrument)))
            else:
                weights = pd.DataFrame(list(map(partial(optimize_weights, prices=prices[:str(year)], instrument=instrument), samples)))
                if len(weights)<2:
                    print('Weights error')
                    break
            result[year]=weights.mean()
            print(year, sample_length)
            output = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(result).transpose()
            output.columns = forecasts.columns
            pl.plot(output)
            display.clear_output(wait=True)
            display.display(pl.gcf())
    return output

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class accountCurve():
    def __init__(self, forecasts, prices, annual_volatility_target=0.25, multiplier = 1, per_contract_cost = 0, slippage = 0, capital=100000, costs=True):

        if prices.index.names[0] == 'Contract':
            prices = prices.reset_index('Contract', drop=True)

        #Adjust for contract multiplier/pricing in pennies
        prices = prices*multiplier/100
        self.prices = prices

        daily_volatility_target = annual_volatility_target/np.sqrt(252)
        instrument_value_volatility = prices.diff().ewm(span=36, min_periods=36).std()

        self.notional_position = (forecasts * daily_volatility_target * capital).divide(10.0 * instrument_value_volatility[forecasts.index], axis=0)
        self.notional_position.dropna(inplace=True)

        #Chunk trades to be at least 10% move in position (to reduce trading costs)
        self.position = chunk_trades(self.notional_position)

        #Round positions to integers
        self.position = np.around(self.notional_position)

        #self.position.mark_to_market = self.position.multiply(prices, axis=0)
        self.trades = self.position.diff()

        #Calculate returns
        self.gross_returns = (prices.diff().shift(-1)*self.position).dropna()

        if costs:
            self.costs = self.trades.abs() * per_contract_cost
            self.slippage = self.trades.abs() * slippage * multiplier/100
            self.returns = (self.gross_returns - self.slippage - self.costs).dropna()
        else:
            self.returns = self.gross_returns

    def sharpe(self):
        return self.returns.mean()/self.returns.std()*np.sqrt(252)

    def losses(self):
        return [z for z in self.returns if z<0]

    def sortino(self):
        returns = self.returns.pct_change()
        return returns.mean()/np.std(losses(returns))*np.sqrt(252)

    def plot(self):
        self.returns.cumsum().plot()

def chunk_trades(A):
    #Take a list of notional positions and filter so that trades are only greater than 10% of notional position
    last = A[0]
    new = []
    for x in A.iteritems():
        if np.abs((x[1]-last)/last) > 0.1:
            new.append(x[1])
            last = x[1]
        else:
            new.append(last)
    s = pd.Series(new, index=A.index)
    return s
```

On my data, this takes around 45 minutes to run.

I'd like to know:

1. Is my approach to parallel processing correct? Should I be using threads instead of processes?
2. Can I reconfigure minimize to finish faster? This is bootstrapping, which is a monte-carlo based sampling method, may not require such an accurate result.
3. Anything else I can do to speed it up?

In an ideal world, I'd like to speed it up an order of magnitude.

Comment: You probably want to start off by using a combination of `cProfile` and `line_profiler` to figure out where your code is spending most of its time.

Comment: How much difference does the parallel bit make?  And how long does a single `minimize` call take?  I'm guessing that `minimize` spends most of its time calling `function`, and that in turn is calling `accountCurve`.  I don't see any descriptions of that.

Comment: I've added accountCurve. Minimize is the slowest part. Using parallel seems to speed things up around 3x (guesstimate).

Comment: I'll investigate line_profiler - I'd not heard of that.

Comment: Also you might want to try out other optimization routines. What is the dimensionality of your problem? If it's rather high-dimensional you might use a projected gradient algorithm instead, especially if -- as you say -- demands on the accuracy of the solution are low.